# VARIAS CONDICIONES EN UNA MISMA LINEA

Tags: python, condiciones

Estoy empezando con Python, y me surgió una duda y después de estar horas buscando no conseguí solucionarlo, hacer un formulario que tengas que ingresar un sinónimo pero no puedes usar las palabras tabú, intenté hacer:

```
if respuesta == "volar" or "vuelo"
```

pero me dí cuenta de que `or` solo sirve para booleanos, ¿me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

La evaluación de la linea que agregas, paso a paso es, para las tres posibilidades que existen:

---

```
respuesta = "foo"

if respuesta == "volar" or "vuelo"
   |__________________|                  |
             |
           False        or  "vuelo"
             |              |______|
             |                  |
             |                 True
             |__________ or_____|   
                         |
                        True
```

---

```
respuesta = "volar"

if respuesta == "volar" or "vuelo"
   |__________________|                  
             |
           True  # La segunda expresión ya ni se evalúa siquira
```

---

```
respuesta = "vuelo"

if respuesta == "volar" or "vuelo"
   |__________________|                  |
             |
           False        or  "vuelo"
             |              |______|
             |                  |
             |                 True
             |________  or______|   
                        |
                       True
```

Por lo que realmente haces:

```
if respuesta == "volar" or True
```

y eso siempre es `True`, tenga `respuesta` el contenido que tenga.

Debes siempre usar el operador de comparación de turno entre cada `or`, `and`, `and not`, `or not`, etc.

```
if respuesta == "volar" or respuesta == "vuelo":
```

Ahora bien ésto es muy poco escalable. Si tienes varias palabras a comparar lo mejor es usar un contenedor y el operador de pertenencia (`in`, `not in`).  Lo más eficiente es un conjunto:

```
palabras_tabu = {"volar", "vuelo"}

if respuesta in palabras_tabu:
    print("¡Eso está prohibido!")
```

Comment: MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS, ERA ALGO QUE ME COMPLICABA MUCHO LAS COSAS, mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como has dicho, el **OR** es para concatenar booleanos. Tu problema reside en que la segunda parte del OR está mal implementada. La forma correcta sería:

```
if (respuesta == "volar" or respuesta == "vuelo"):
    # ....
```